# Kinect assembly can not be loaded

Tags: c#, kinect

I try to create a Kinect application for Xbox, but when I build the project, the following error occurs;

> Type or assembly not found: Microsoft.Research - Are you missing...

But the assembly is loaded and referenced in the project and also in the "using" header of the file using it.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are all the dependencies of Microsoft.Research also in the directory?  Sounds like deployment is simply missing some of them.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth How can I check this? There is only one assembly file in the microsoft kinect SDK directory.

Comment: A colleague had a similar problem the other day, I think it was because he was targeting a the .NET 4 Client Profile. Switching to the full profile solved his problem.

Comment: @madd0 I can't select a target profile - It's an Xbox application, so I can't select between different target frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check what is your "platform" target is ?

Maybe xbox need a specific platform or the libs are only available for one platform (as need to generate explicitily for x86_64 only).

Just asking.

Comment: So I finally figured it out - you were right, but only partially. I created the project as an Xbox360-Game - but apparently you can't use the freely available Kinect SDK to develop on Xboxes - only on PCs. So, it really was the target platform, although not the one you can select in the project settings ;) You have to create the project as a Windows Game, then it works just fine. To develop Kinect on Xbox, you need to get the SDK directly from Microsoft which is quite a hard thing to do... unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have selected "Local Copy" into the properties of each library in references in your project ?

Comment: Is that necessary? All references I currently have in the project are selected as "Local copy: false" - but the `Microsoft.Research` is the only one making problems.

Comment: I don't know, it's just an idea probably worthing to be tested :)